# How to place any UI element at the end of text that is trimmed

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a custom control that contains TextBlock and Ellipse.
I want to have this Ellipse placed in a position where the TextBlock ends. If there is lack of space text should be trimmed and Ellipse should remain at its position. I have created very simple sample to illustrate the problem.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="MainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Grid Height="50">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:TextWithEllipse x:Name="Control1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <local:TextWithEllipse x:Name="Control2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        Control1.Text = "One two three four five six seven eight nine ten One two three four five six seven eight nine ten";
        Control2.Text = "Short text";
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control1.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
        Control2.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
    }
}
```

what is done: the TextWithEllipse controls are getting the same width as the app window has and some texts are written to them - short and long one.

Here is how this control looks like:

TextWithEllipse.xaml.cs:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="TextResize.TextWithEllipse"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="MediumPurple">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" MinWidth="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="TestTitle"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="16"/>

    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

</Grid>
```

TextWithEllipse.cs:

```
public sealed partial class TextWithEllipse : UserControl
{
    public TextWithEllipse()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return TestTitle.Text; }
        set { TestTitle.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

It works OK if the text width is less than controls width. If the text is long and takes more space it is going outside the window, Ellipse is not shown unless you the windows width is extended.
When the first Column width is changed to '*':

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="20" MinWidth="20"/>
```

the situation is than while the text takes more width than window, the text is being trimmed and Ellipse is in the right place. But if the text is short, the Ellipse will not be placed right after the text, but at the end of window.

[image: Image illustrating the problem]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with your code a bit to find a solution. As you found out setting `ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"` won't work because it tells the `TextBlock` that it has as much space as it needs, so it will never trim. So setting `ColumnDefinition Width="*"` is the right way to go, but as a little detail change the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the whole `Grid` to `Left`, because then the whole `Grid` will only stretch if it is required (which will happen when you have a lot of text). The whole code would be:

```
<Grid Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="MediumPurple">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" MinWidth="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="TestTitle"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="16"/>

    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

</Grid>
```

This at least in the XAML Designer gives me the behavior you would like to have.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use *RelativePanel*:

```
<RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="TestTitle" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="16" Padding="0,0,20,0"/>
    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red" RelativePanel.AlignRightWith="TestTitle"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

You also don't need to change width in *OnSizeChanged* - it will change automatically even without this event.

Comment: thanks for help, altough I have marked schumi1331 reply as the answer because it fits better the design I already have

Comment: @RTDev No problem with that. Note, that technically in your picture *What I want* shows that purple background should be through the full window's width - that is the difference between those two solutions (though, of course it can be achieved other ways). Everything depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: yes, Indeed - but I can always wrap the whole control in one more grid to have the colour - my actual situation is simpler because this control won't have any background at all - it's just for demostration, and my actual layout is far more complicated - I have tried to take the part that shows my isse